# Processbuilder to run Batch file and pythonscript

Tags: java, python

My requirement is i have to run Batch file located in **(C:\Users\Vk\TestBatch.bat)** under **C:\users\VK\Logs**(This is the path in which i have to run the batch file). After that i have to run the python script. I have to do this by using ProcessBuilder. Below is the piece of code i am using, but unfortunately it is not working.

```
String[] command ={"cmd.exe","/C","cd C:\\Users\\vk\\Logs","C:\\users\\Vk\\TestBatch.bat",
"C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.3\\python.exe","C:\\Users\\vk\TestScript2.py"}; 
                    probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command );
```

Can any one suggest me how to run this batch file in other location and followed by the execution of python script.

Thanks,
Sudheer

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to achieve this.

1. Either add your python executable in your System Path.
2. You can go to the particular directory where executable is located and run the python script.

   ```
     a. Go to Directory where batch file is located.
     b. Run batch file by simply putting the name.
     c. go to home directory by command cd
     d. go to directory where python executable is present.
     e. run python script using command `py <scriptName>`
   ```

```
String [] command = {"cd C:\users\Vk", "TestBatch", "cd", "cd C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\", "py TestScript2.py"};
ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Here i want to execute batch file under other folder means i have to go to location C:\users\vk\Logs under this location i have to execute Batchfile(This file is in C;\users\Vk\TestBatch).

Comment: thats what I have written.. see first command, you go to that directory vk and then run batch command using second command i.e. `TestBatch`

Comment: I tried what you suggested. I am getting below error.

Comment: Java.io.IOException : Cannot run program "cd C:\Users\Vk\logs" : CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: The same thing i have achieved by using windows command prompt using below steps.1)cd :\Users\Vk\logs and after that 2)"C:\Users\Vk\TestBatch" how to do the same by using processBuilder?